# How to properly decode PDF from String on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-file

I am trying to create an app that will store some PDf files as base64 encoded Strings in a database and then later decode them and dispay them (with an Intent to open other PDF reader).
But something doesn't work properly. I know that the byte array is the same before and after storage as encoded String, so that isn't the problem.
I think the problem is somewhere in the process of creating a File to open with the intent, but I'm not sure.

Creating the String:

```
 byte[] b = Files.toByteArray(pdf);
 String encodedFile = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

pdf is the File I get from this:

```
else if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            String fileName = uri.toString();
            fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.length()-10);
            service.addPDF(order, fileName, new File(uri.getPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateFileList();
    }
```

Getting File from String:

```
 case PDF:
    try {
        byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(file.getContent(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        File dir = getStorageDir();
        File pdffile = new File(dir, file.getName());
        if(!pdffile.exists())
        {
            pdffile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            pdffile.createNewFile();
        }
        Files.write(pdfAsBytes, pdffile);
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdffile), "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;
```

This code runs with no errors, but the PDF viewer cannot display the file. I have tried with several viewers. I suspect the resulting file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to save to external storage instead of the dir.

```
File dir = getStorageDir();
```

Should be

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Then it works.